# Convexity and spectral inclusion in numerical range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am studying numerical range from *Numerical Range: The Field of Values of Linear Operators
and Matrices* by Gustafson and Rao. While proving Theorem 1.2-1 (Spectral Inclusion), the authors assert the following:

> It is well known (see, for example, [H], Problem 63) that the boundary of
> the spectrum is contained in the approximate point spectrum $\sigma _{app}$, which
> consists of complex numbers $\lambda$ for which there exists a sequence of unit
> vectors $\{f_n\}$ with $||(T - AI) f_n || \to 0$. Since $W(T)$ is convex, it suffices to
> show that $\sigma_{app}(T) \subset W(T)$.

I don't understand why it suffices to show $\sigma_{app}(T) \subset W(T)$ to conclude $\sigma(T) \subset W(T)$. What roles do the inclusion of the boundary $\partial \sigma (T)$ in $\sigma _{app} (T)$ and the convexity of $W(T)$ play?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that the inclusions $\sigma_{\rm app}(T)\subset W(T)$ and $\sigma(T)\subset  W(T)$ are false in general. What is true is that they lie in the *closure* of $W(T)$.

Let $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$. If $\lambda\in\partial \sigma(T)$, then $\lambda\in \overline{W(T)}$, so we may assume that $\lambda$ is an interior point. Let $\rho\in\sigma(T)\setminus\{\lambda\}$, which exists because $\lambda$ is interior. We may assume without loss of generality that $\lambda\ne0$ and $\rho=0$, because we can replace $T$ with $T-\rho I$.

Let $L=\{t\lambda:\ t\in\mathbb R\}$. As $L$ is closed and $\sigma(T)$ is compact, the set $L\cap\sigma(T)$ is compact. As the function $t\,\lambda\longmapsto t$ is continuous with compact domain, it achieves its maximum and minimum. So there exist $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb R$ such that $t_1\lambda\in\sigma(T)$, $t_2\lambda\in\sigma(T)$ and $(t_1+\varepsilon)\lambda\not\in\sigma(T)$, $(t_2-\varepsilon)\lambda\not\in\sigma(T)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Then $t_1\lambda,t_2\lambda\in \partial\sigma(T)\subset \overline{W(T)}$.

Note that $t_1>1$ and $t_2<1$ since $\lambda\in L\cap\sigma(T)$ and $\lambda\not\in\partial\sigma(T)$. Then
$$
\lambda=\frac{1-t_2}{t_1-t_2}\,t_1\lambda+\frac{t_1-1}{t_1-t_2}\,t_2\lambda\in \overline{W(T)}. 
$$

---

One can avoid the whole argument  above by noting that if $\lambda\not\in\sigma_{\rm app}(T)$ then $\lambda\in \sigma_r(T)$. This means that $\overline{\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda I)}\subsetneq H$. Then $\ker(T^*-\overline\lambda I)=\overline{\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda I)}^\perp\ne\{0\}$. That is, $\overline\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T^*$. Given a unit vector $x$ with $T^*x=\overline\lambda x$, we have
$$
\lambda=\langle x,\overline\lambda x\rangle=\langle x,T^*x\rangle=\langle Tx,x\rangle\in W(T). 
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering! Helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please upvote the answers that you find useful.

Comment: Sorry I can't vote as of now (not enough reputation) but I'll definitely vote once my reputation improves a bit.

Comment: No worries. Whenever you can it will be fine.